# Laptop cause monitor to flicker/not display

Tags: laptop, display

Hey so I've been having this problem with my laptop for around 2-3 weeks now. I had my laptop (Dell XPS 15 9570) for around 6 years now and I haven't had any problems with it until recently. Around 3 weeks ago my main laptop screen stopped displaying for a few minutes, but after I restarted it went back to normal. Then a few days later I noticed my monitor screen start flickering. Before it wasn't often, my screen would quickly stop displaying for like a second then would reappear and be fine for like another 30-40 minutes before doing it again. Then it later became every few seconds it would do this.

I tried seeing if it was a monitor issue so I connected my Switch to my monitor so if that it caused the same issue and it didn't, then I tried connecting my laptop to another monitor in my house and the issue happened again so it forsure my laptop problem. I tried to find many solutions online like updating/reinstalling graphic card, disabling windows error reporting systems, I even tried to update to windows 11 to see if that changed anything and it didn't work either. Then I tried a solution where I changed the refresh rate for the monitor, changing the refresh rate didn't really work until I tried changing it to 60 Hz (interlaced). That solution worked, the image wasn't as good as it use to be but at least it worked... for about a week then the problem started happening again. Now its to the point where my monitor screen is constantly black and it flickers the actual image for a few seconds then goes back to being a black screen.

Any idea what the issue could be and how to solve it?

TLDR: when I connect my laptop to any monitor, the image either flickers every few seconds or nothing displays for a few seconds, image appears for a second then goes away again. Already tried different wires, power outlets, updating/reinstalling drivers, changing refresh rates, disable windows error reporting systems and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Reasonable suggestions for this:  (1) the ribbon connecting cable has become intermittent.  (2) the screen illumination part has become intermittent or defective.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I am currently using Windows 11 but the issue still happened while I was on windows 10, I actually tried upgrading to windows 11 to see if that was the problem but it wasn't, I'll remove both tags

Comment: @John is there a way to test if this is the issue/fix the issue?

Comment: No way to test.  You (or a skilled person) would need to take the laptop apart to test.